# Pass a large buffer using P-Invoke

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I need to pass a buffer containing audio stream from C# to native dll. Buffer resides in struct. It's desirable that buffer will pass via interface & not via disk path. I've seen this method:

```
// native
struct MyStruct 
{
    short* buffer
}
void Foo(MyStruct *myStruct);

// managed
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=1000)]
    public short[] buffer;
}

[DllImport("My.dll")]
public static extern void Foo(ref MyStruct myStruct);
```

First question is if this code is correct for short* buffer of size up to 1K shorts?

Second, size is unkown in advance: do I need to set maximum size in SizeConst (could be several MB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the two structures in your question don't match. The C# structure would match

```
struct MyStruct
{
    short arr[1000];
};
```

That's what `ByValArray` means – an array allocated inline in the structure.

If the size is dynamic (that is only known at runtime), then you probably should not expect to get the marshaller to handle this for you. You certainly don't want to force marshalling to a constant sized buffer every time because that will be inefficient. In fact you really want to avoid copying the buffer around at all. And the p/invoke marshaler has an upper limit on the size of objects that it is prepared to marshal.

It is going to be far cleaner and efficient to pin the array manually, and pass its address. And you should also pass the length of the array so that the C++ code knows how much it is expected to read.

On the C++ side:

```
struct BufferStruct
{
    int len;
    short* arr;
};

void Foo(const BufferStruct buffer);
```

On the C# side:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct BufferStruct
{
    public int len;
    public IntPtr arr;
}

[DllImport("My.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Foo(BufferStruct buffer);
```

Then you call the function like this:

```
short[] arr = ...;
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    BufferStruct buffer;
    buffer.len = buffer.Length;
    buffer.arr = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    Foo(buffer);
}
finally
{
    gch.Free();
}
```

All of this would be easier still if you did not force the array into a struct. If you passed the length and array as parameters, then the marshaller would pin the array for you and make the code even simpler.